# How to remove category titles?

Tags: categories, archives, title

When I go into certain categories, there is a page title that says "Category: category_name", like this:

[image]

I would like to remove the "Category" from that title.
I've already looked around quite a bit and found nothing that works for me. Most answers say to edit the category.php file which doesn't exist in the theme I am using or go to archive.php which doesn't seem to have anything relevant to the category title.

On archive.php, the only seemingly relevant code that even mentions category is this:

```
     <?php if ( is_tag() || is_category() || is_tax() ) { ?>
        <div class="archive-description"><?php the_archive_description(); ?></div>
    <?php } ?>
```

I don't think it's relevant at all to what I am trying to do.

So, does anyone know how I can remove the category from the title? By the way, the theme I am using is Tesseract.

Answer (score 1):

You can find in **inc/template-tags.php** file.

```
if ( is_category() ) {
    $title = sprintf( __( 'Category: %s', 'tesseract' ), single_cat_title( '', false ) );
}
```

Comment: When I saw this, it made all the sense in the world, however it did not work :( It did nothing. Here's the page looking the exact same as it did before: http://topnewsreporters.com/category/entertainment/ and the code:

if ( is_category() ) {
  $title = sprintf( __( 'BLablabla: %s', 'tesseract' ), single_cat_title( '', false ) );
 }